# SQL zero won't appear in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have this query in my sql...

```
DECLARE @earninglist varchar(1000)
       Set @earninglist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],['
            +LTRIM([Description]) FROM
            PR_Earnings 
            ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM([Description])
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '')+']'


DECLARE @chargeslist varchar(1000)
    Set @chargeslist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],['
            +LTRIM([ChargesTypeName]) FROM
            PRChargesAdvancesTypes 
            ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM([ChargesTypeName])
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '')+']'
  Declare @sql varchar(max)
  Set @sql=
   'Select Name,BranchId,Basic,'+@earninglist+',Overtime,[Paid Hol],[Sunday OT],
     [Gross Amount],[WithTax],[SSS Cont],[SSS Loan],[Pagibig Cont],[Pagibig Loan]
     ,Medicare,'+@chargeslist+',[Total Ded],[Net with OD],[Net no OD]
    from
     (
      Select distinct 
        pr_employees.Fullname as Name
       ,PR_Employees.BranchID,PR_payroll.BasicPay as Basic
       ,PR_Empearnings.EarningAmt
       ,PR_Earnings.Description
       ,pr_payroll.Overtime
       ,Pr_payroll.SundayOT as [Sunday OT]
       ,Pr_Payroll.PaidHol as [Paid Hol]
       ,pr_payroll.ThirteenthMonthPay as [Thirteen MO]
       ,pr_payroll.Grosspay as [Gross Amount]
       ,pr_payroll.WithHoldingTax as [WithTax]
       ,pr_payroll.SSSPremium as [SSS Cont]
       ,pr_payroll.SSSLoan as [SSS Loan]
       ,pr_payroll.PagibigPremium as [Pagibig Cont]
       ,pr_payroll.PagibigLoan as [Pagibig Loan]
       ,pr_payroll.NHIPPremium as Medicare
       ,pr_payroll.TotalDeductions as [Total Ded]
       ,pr_Payroll.netpay as [Net with OD]
       ,pr_payroll.netnoOd as [Net no OD]
       ,prchargesAdvances.Credit
       ,prchargesadvancesTypes.ChargesTypeName
     from pr_employees
      left join pr_payroll on PR_Employees.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
      left join PR_EmpEarnings on PR_Payroll.EmpID=PR_EmpEarnings.EmpID
      left join PR_Earnings on PR_EmpEarnings.EarningId=pr_earnings.earningid
      left join PR_Overtime on PR_Overtime.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
      left join PRChargesAdvances on PRChargesAdvances.transactiondate=pr_payroll.period   
       and prchargesadvances.empid=pr_payroll.empid
      left join PRChargesAdvancesTypes on PRChargesAdvances.ChargeTypeID=PRChargesAdvancesTypes.ChargesTypeID
     where PR_Payroll.Period=''8/31/2013''  
  ) as Source
  pivot 
  (
     MAX([EarningAmt])
     FOR [Description] IN ('+@earninglist +') 
  ) as pvt
   pivot 
  (
     MAX([Credit])
     FOR [ChargesTypeName] IN ('+@chargeslist +') 
  ) as pvt2
  ;'
  EXEC (@sql)
```

the output of this would be:

```
Name    BranchID     Basics     Allowance    Cola    incentives  
 name1      1        5000                    200       250
 name2      2        3000        250                   100
```

Is there a way that I could put zero instead of blank in the field of allowance and cola??

please help badly need it thanks..

Comment: I just make a sample query and a sample output....

Comment: I just have to say that query is absolutely not readable.. It doesn't help in getting people to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
ISNULL(MAX([EarningAmt]),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is replace `EarningAmt` `NULL` values with a `0`.
You can accomplish this using [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
ISNULL(MAX([EarningAmt]),0)
```

Basically, as mentioned in the documentation, it:

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

Where the `replacement value` in your case is `0`.